# Upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04 - Unity not loading

Tags: unity, upgrade, 13.04

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu dist to 13.04 (from 12.10), after the upgrade when i log in my desktop isn't loading unity. 
I can access my Terminal (through Ctrl+Alt+T) and most apps through it, i tried reseting Compiz with no success, and even tried reinstalling my graphics card driver (AMD ATI Catalyst Radeon HD 4800), but it can't install because it says it's missing a module (/lib/modules/3.8.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h)
Anyone can give me a hand to recover my Desktop?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue.
I went through many websites, and found that `unity --replace` might help. Try this if it recovers for you, its not recovering for me.